# Apache Camel FTP - Get List of Files

Tags: apache-camel

Hy,

I'm currently facing the challenge, that I need to get a List of all children in an FTP folder.
Unfortunatelly I'm not searching for a specific file, or I would just use a filter, but I need the actual list of files, with all their meta-data.
I do this because I then compare that list to the children of a local folder to create a kind of report.

I tried using `pollEnrich()` with the consumer to get the files individually and then aggregate them, but the issue is, that I don't have a completion condition as I don't know the number of files, that will arrive.

I thought about using the `FTPClient` directly, but it does not make much sense to create a client myself, when camel already has such good handling of the FTPClient. I would basically copy paste the camel component code, which is nonsense.

Any ideas?

Edit:
I just realized, that the ftp consumer also skips folders, which makes sense for its original use case (loading files), but makes this even harder, as I also need the folder.

Best regards
Chris

Comment: You can try with download=false, then the camel-ftp component will give your all the file names / metadata

Comment: Hm, I guess I could use that with pollEnrich() and the BatchComplete property to aggregate them. Unfortunatelly this only loads the files and not the sub-folders, which I also need